# Loop through pages with certain template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, loops

Hi is there a way to loop through wordpress pages that are using a certain template?

Comment: Have any source code to show us where you are stuck?   It's hard to determine what your question is without more specific detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

```
$template = 'NAME';
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template', 'meta_value' => $template.'.php' ) );

while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    ...
endwhile;
```